# how to scan my wifi connection?

Tags: wireless, security

I used to do it with SoftPerfect Wifi Guard, but 1.0.6 new version isn't allowed for Linux and I can't find previous version 1.0.5.
The target is identify all devices connected into my wireless network.
Thanks

Comment: nmap ~ best ever

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your preference, you could try the command line utility [nmap](https://nmap.org/), or its GUI-based counterpart [Zenmap](https://nmap.org/zenmap/) for device discovery (among others).

Comment: I was looking for something more simple, but Zenmap will be useful in the meanwhile. Thanks